# Derivation of the Y-Combinator

Tags: lambda-calculus, y-combinator

While going through this [article](https://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html) about Y-combinator (which I highly recommend), I stumbled over this transformation :

```
(define Y 
    (lambda (f)
      ((lambda (x) (x x))
       (lambda (x) (f (x x))))))

Note that we can apply the inner lambda expression to its argument to get an equivalent version of Y:

  (define Y 
    (lambda (f)
      ((lambda (x) (f (x x)))
       (lambda (x) (f (x x))))))
```

Could someone please explain me how did we get to the second version of Y? Which steps did we follow to get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `(lambda (x) (x x))(lambda (x) (f (x x)))`
Do the application to get `(lambda (x) (f (x x))(lambda (x) (f (x x))`
Notice the left lambda creates 2 copies of its argument, which is the right lambda.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. It was not trivial for to spot the application/beta reduction.